# Creating a Visual Studio Code integrated terminal with a custom Node script as the shell

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, electron, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a Visual Studio Code extension in which I hope to create a terminal which gives access to a custom shell. I have a Node.js script (`.js` file) which implements this shell. **Now, I'm trying to use Code's `createTerminal` method from my extension to launch a terminal that uses my Node.js script as its shell.**

I can't directly set the `shellPath` to be my `js` file, because I have no guarantee that the user has Node.js installed, that the system will run such files with Node.js, nor what version of Node is installed. I need to be able to point at a universally-understood binary which can handle the file. Roughly speaking, I want to do this:

```
let terminal = vscode.window.createTerminal({
    name: "My terminal",
    shellPath: 'node', // Use the Node.js executable as the target
    shellArgs: [path.join(__dirname, 'my-shell-wrapper.js')] // Tell Node to run my shell
});
terminal.show();
```

How can I accomplish this? Is there an executable that ships with Code that I can point to which runs Node scripts? Or is there another mechanism which I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSCode now (as of the past year or so) has the option of specifying custom behaviors for terminals aside from just the underlying shell executable. [`createTerminal`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.createTerminal) has an overload which takes [`ExtensionTerminalOptions`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionTerminalOptions); this has a `pty` property which allows you to specify custom handlers for reading from and writing to the terminal. From their [Pseudoterminal documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Pseudoterminal):

```
const writeEmitter = new vscode.EventEmitter<string>();
const pty: vscode.Pseudoterminal = {
  onDidWrite: writeEmitter.event,
  open: () => {},
  close: () => {},
  handleInput: data => writeEmitter.fire(data === '\r' ? '\r\n' : data)
};
vscode.window.createTerminal({ name: 'Local echo', pty });
```

This can be used to implement arbitrary terminal interactions.